# docker-compose and Dockerfile do not install drupal

Tags: docker, docker-compose, drupal-7, dockerfile

New to docker and I wanted to install Drupal 7 with docker, to mirror our production server environment. (We are getting ready to upgrade to Drupal 8 - not relevant to this question here.) When I run docker-compose the docker container and an app folder is created, but there is nothing inside app/ . I then placed a composer.json in the root to run composer and install drupal 7. That works, but I thought the point of docker-compose was that it would install everything including drupal 7.
What am I doing wrong?

Follow up question:
Since I am trying to mirror the drupal site on the production server environment, I need to install drupal version 7.69, but this version is not listed on Docker Hub as a package. So, I can't install that specific version?

```
Docker 19.03.13
MacOS 10.14.6
LAMP
MySQL databases not in volume, but served from Mac development environment
```

Directory structure:

```
root
|--apache-drupal.conf
|--docker-compose.yml
|--Dockerfile
|--composer.json
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM drupal:7.73-apache

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y \
    automake \
    bsdmainutils \
    build-essential \
    ssh \
    unzip \
    curl \
    libopenmpi-dev \
    openmpi-bin \
    git \
    default-mysql-client \
    vim \
    wget \
    zlib1g-dev

# Install Composer
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');" && \
    php composer-setup.php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer && \
    php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" && \
    ln -s /root/.composer/vendor/bin/drush /usr/local/bin/drush

RUN cp /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini && \
    sed -i -e "s/^ *memory_limit.*/memory_limit = -1/g" /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini && \
    sed -i -e "s/^ *upload_max_filesize.*/upload_max_filesize = 30M/g" /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

# Install Drush
RUN composer global require drush/drush:8.2 && \
    composer global update

#RUN wget -O drush.phar https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/releases/download/0.4.2/drush.phar && \
#   chmod +x drush.phar && \
#   mv drush.phar /usr/local/bin/drush

# Clean repository
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/www/html/* && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY apache-drupal.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

WORKDIR /app
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  drupal:
    image: userID/website_d7:1.0
    container_name: website_d7
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8033:80"
    extra_hosts:
      - "test.docker:127.0.0.1"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASS: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: website_d7
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app:cached
    restart: always
```

Running docker containers with:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 0):

I personnaly never installed drupal from docker / docker-compose ; I always used composer to do it which is in my opinion better cause you can manage the drupal version you want and the modules you need in the `composer.json`. I only use docker / docker-compose to build the environment and the containers (database / frontend / backend / cache manager).

Comment: Thanks. Do you still put the Drupal package (version) in the Dockerfile or that is not necessary? Are you just creating PHP-Apache (or equivalent) containers?

Comment: I am only mounting a PHP-nginx container (+ others containers such as mariadb, phpmyadmin, varnish or memcached). Not necessary to put the drupal package in the dockerfile when doing it like that, only in the `composer.json`.

Answer (score 0):

under `volumes:`, you are mounting your local `./app` folder INTO the container, overwriting `/app` inside the container. so, if there is nothing in it to begin with, then it wont be filled by your docker container being created.

On the [Drupal Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal) (under the volumes heading) they talk about adding 4 volume mounts for specific folders, like:

```
volumes:
  - /path/on/host/modules:/var/www/html/modules
  - /path/on/host/profiles:/var/www/html/profiles
  - /path/on/host/sites:/var/www/html/sites
  - /path/on/host/themes:/var/www/html/themes
```

if you put all those into your `./app` folder locally, you might end up with something like:

```
volumes:
  - ./app/modules:/var/www/html/modules
  - ./app/profiles:/var/www/html/profiles
  - ./app/sites:/var/www/html/sites
  - ./app/themes:/var/www/html/themes
```

generally, I like to use docker for containerizing the environment/runtime/third party systems (like Drupal or more often in my case WordPress) and then I setup volumes similar to the above for specific folder(s) that are unique to the project (like themes, plugins, etc.). In my case, I usually do WordPress development, so I just have a single mount for `./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content`

RE: your follow up question - if you look at the "Tags" tab on that same docker hub page (or [search for 7.69 on there](https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal?tab=tags&page=1&name=7.69)) you'll see it is actually listed there, so it should be available.

Comment: Great info, thanks! Do you have to link those volumes up (like you would do with a mysql volume) or is that not necessary? Also what is the advantage of putting those folders in  those volumes over using composer?

Comment: you don't "have" to create them. adding "volumes" just creates a link between your host  and the container. In this case, linking folders relative to the project folder / compose file. Alternatively, you could do something like `- db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data` along with defining `volumes:\n  db_data:` at the end of your compose file, which would create a volume called "db_data" located in the system/global docker volumes directory. I usually use the first type for project files and the latter for saving things like database data (otherwise you loose data between starts / deploys)

Comment: I still don't understand the part you mentioned at the end: `otherwise you loose data between starts / deploys`.  What starts? Is `losing data` an issue when I use `docker-compose up -d` if I don't use multiple volumes, but just one (e.g. drupal)?